# ng2-file-upload single request clearQueue() not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-file-upload

The uploader multiple files in one request so customized file uploads after getting a response using  clearQueue() not working get single file only removed

> core.js:3926 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'abort' of
>   undefined
>       at FileUploaderCustom.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-uploader.class.js.FileUploader.cancelItem
>   (file-uploader.class.js:112)
>       at FileItem.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-item.class.js.FileItem.cancel
>   (file-item.class.js:38)
>       at FileUploaderCustom.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-uploader.class.js.FileUploader.removeFromQueue
>   (file-uploader.class.js:85)
>       at FileItem.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-item.class.js.FileItem.remove
>   (file-item.class.js:41)
>       at FileUploaderCustom.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-uploader.class.js.FileUploader.clearQueue
>   (file-uploader.class.js:92)
>       at FileUploaderCustom.uploaderOnward.onSuccessItem (mandate-initial.component.ts:267)
>       at FileUploaderCustom.push../node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-uploader.class.js.FileUploader._onSuccessItem (file-uploader.class.js:396)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYload] (fileUploader.ts:71)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:1255)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:431)

customized file uploads .ts

```
export class FileUploaderCustom extends FileUploader {

    constructor(
        options: FileUploaderOptions
    ) {
        super(options);
    }

    uploadAllFiles(): void {
        // const _this = this;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const sendable = new FormData();
        const fakeItem: FileItem = null;
        this.onBuildItemForm(fakeItem, sendable);

        for (const item of this.queue) {
            item.headers = [];
            item.withCredentials = true;
            item.formData = [];
            item.isReady = true;
            item.isUploading = true;
            item.isUploaded = false;
            item.isSuccess = false;
            item.isCancel = false;
            item.isError = false;
            item.progress = 0;
            item.index = void 0;
            if (typeof item._file.size !== 'number') {
                throw new TypeError('The file specified is no longer valid');
            }
            sendable.append('file', item._file, item.file.name);
        }

        if (this.options.additionalParameter !== undefined) {
            Object.keys(this.options.additionalParameter).forEach((key) => {
                sendable.append(key, this.options.additionalParameter[key]);
            })
        }

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            this.onErrorItem(fakeItem, null, xhr.status, null);
        }

        xhr.onabort = () => {
            this.onErrorItem(fakeItem, null, xhr.status, null);
        }

        xhr.open('POST', this.options.url, true);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        if (this.options.headers) {
            for (let _i = 0, _a = this.options.headers; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
                const header = _a[_i];
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
            }
        }
        if (this.authToken) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(this.authTokenHeader, this.authToken);
        }

        xhr.onload = () => {
            const headers = this._parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            const response = this._transformResponse(xhr.response, headers);
            const gist = this._isSuccessCode(xhr.status) ? 'Success' : 'Error';
            const method = '_on' + gist + 'Item';
            for (const item of this.queue) {
                this[method](item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            }
            this._onCompleteItem(this.queue[0], response, xhr.status, headers);
        }

        xhr.send(sendable);
    }
}
```

responses

```
this.uploaderUpdate.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
      this.uploadResult = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(this.uploadResult)
      if (this.uploadResult.rescode == "0000") {
        this.uploaderUpdate.clearQueue();
        this.editMyContainer = !this.editMyContainer;
        this.toastyService.success(this.uploadResult.Description);
      } else if (this.uploadResult.rescode == "0001") {
        this.toastyService.error(this.uploadResult.ErrorDescription);

      } else if (this.uploadResult.rescode == "0002") {
        this.toastyService.error(this.uploadResult.ErrorDescription);
      }
    };
```